# Pass a protocol as a method argument

Tags: objective-c, methods, protocols, arguments

First let me explain what I don't mean. I don't want to type an argument to a protocol:

```
-(void)someMethod:(id<SomeProtocol>)someArgument;
```

What I do want to is to pass a protocol to a method in the same way I can pass a Class to a method (The following is incorrect, but it hopefully explains what I want to do):

```
-(void)someMethod:(Protocol)someArgument;
```

I would then like to be able to use the Protocol to check whether a set of objects implement it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you know the name of a protocol at coding-time, use `@protocol(SomeProtocol)` to get a pointer to that protocol, similar to how you'd use `@selector(x)`.

Beyond that, you just refer to protocols with the class identifier `Protocol` -- so you're method declaration would look like:

```
-(void)someMethod:(Protocol*)someArgument
```

You can see an example in the docs for `NSObject conformsToProtocol:`

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/conformsToProtocol:

Comment: Thanks. So out of interest why does Protocol use a pointer while Class doesn't?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have answer to that, myself.  Good question, though.

Comment: Protocols and classes are each represented by their own classes. The difference is, the _word_ `Class` is [defined as being a pointer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-objc_class), but `Protocol` is just the name of the class, like any other (`NSString`, e.g.); so for a [`Protocol` instance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF149) you must have an explicit pointer. @1nd

Comment: @1ndivisible: Protocol is a class, just like NSString or NSArray. `Class` is not a class, it's a type that signifies a pointer to a class, much the same as `id` signifies a pointer to objects.

Answer (score 3):

Protocol is a class, so you just write `- (void)someMethod:(Protocol *)someArgument` like with any other object type. You can see this in the declaration for `conformsToProtocol:`:

```
+ (BOOL)conformsToProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void) executeRequest:(id<Protocol1>)request andCompletion:(id<Protocol2>)response
```

***the only way to pass protocol into an argument***

because **id<..>** means it needs to conform to that protocol before pass throw the argument

Comment: perfect , this something others not mentioning

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using protocol. It will obscure which interface your code actually relies on. Use `id<yourprotocol>*`.  This is actually how the cocoa frameworks pass protocols. Forgive the use of words if I don't it thinks I'm trying to do HTML.

Comment: Also this is a strongly typed language so don't try and make it act loosely typed

Comment: Is this down voted because it's not what OP wants? This is what I want... `@protocol(MyProtocol)varname` didn't even compile for me.